# Applescript to rename a file in the applications folder

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to use a script to rename a text file in the applications folder. I'm trying the following

```
tell application "Finder"

    set name of file "File.txt" of applications folder to "File.txt.OFF"

end tell
```

But this gives an error:

```
Can’t get file "Text.txt" of applications folder.
```

Its definitely in there and called that (it's a copy and paste). I then tried removing the folder bit:

```
set name of file "File.txt" of applications to "File.txt.OFF"
```

But got another error:

```
Finder got an error: Can’t set every application to "Text.txt.OFF".
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`applications folder` in Finder terminology does not point to the standard folder `/Applications`. It seems to be a legacy reference to some pre OS X item.

Try this, but you might not have permission to change the name and you are discouraged anyway from putting arbitrary data like text files into `/Applications`

```
set applicationsFolder to path to applications folder
tell application "Finder"
    set name of file "File.txt" of applicationsFolder to "File.txt.OFF"
end tell
```

or use `System Events`

```
tell application "System Events"
    set name of file "File.txt" of applications folder of local domain to "File.txt.OFF"
end tell
```